# Optimization for a high time complexity problem (4Sum)

Tags: python, time-complexity

This is question from Leetcode. I derived this solution based on the idea of 3Sum problem.

The question is :

Given an array nums of n integers and an integer target, are there elements a, b, c, and d in nums such that a + b + c + d = target? Find all unique quadruplets in the array which gives the sum of target.

For example

```
Given array nums = [1, 0, -1, 0, -2, 2], and target = 0.

A solution set is:
[
  [-1,  0, 0, 1],
  [-2, -1, 1, 2],
  [-2,  0, 0, 2]
]
```

My solution.

```
class Solution(object):
    def fourSum(self, nums, target):
        answer = []
        nums.sort()
        for i in range(len(nums)-3):
            # print('node 1')
            for j in range(i+1,len(nums)-2):
                # print('node 2')
                k,w = j+1,len(nums)-1
                while k < w:
                    sum = nums[i]+nums[j]+nums[k]+nums[w]
                    if  sum == target and [nums[i],nums[j],nums[k],nums[w]] not in answer:
                        answer.append([nums[i],nums[j],nums[k],nums[w]])
                    if  sum > target:
                        w-=1
                    else:
                        k+=1
        return answer
```

However, the speed of the algorithm is not ideal.

Can small changes be done to speed up the algorithms?

Any redundancy in this code?
Thanks

Comment: What is the minimum time complexity you need?

Comment: One more thing, I would like you to post some test cases. Thanks!

Comment: @Ava I am currently doing a O(n3) algorithm. That is the best i could think off. You were right, I have put a test sample

Comment: @Leo No, you're currently O(n^6). See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Can small changes be done to speed up the algorithms.

Is that a question.

But yes. Your mistake is just the `not in answer` test, as `answer` is a list (of lists). Make it a set (of tuples) instead. If needed, convert to list of lists at the end. (If you're doing this [on LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/4sum/), the judge might accept the incorrect type anyway.)

This turns your current O(n^6) solution into an O(n^3) solution. For example:

```
nums = list(range(50))
target = 98
With list:  0.697 seconds
With set:   0.062 seconds

nums = list(range(100))
target = 198
With list: 48.921 seconds
With set:   0.304 seconds
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining why making the list a tuple can shrink the time complexity?

Comment: @Leo Where did you get that from? That's not what I said.

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm going to use python, I would rather try to do it in a pythonic way.

```py
from itertools import combinations

def fourSum(nums, target):
    return list({
        num for num in combinations(nums, 4)
        if sum(num) == target
    })

print(fourSum([1, 0, -1, 0, -2, 2], 0))
```

To compare my code's execution time with yours, I even wrote the following script.

```py
from itertools import combinations
import timeit, random

def myFourSum(nums, target):
    return list({
        num for num in combinations(nums, 4)
        if sum(num) == target
    })
    
def yourFourSum(nums, target):
    answer = []
    nums.sort()
    for i in range(len(nums)-3):
        # print('node 1')
        for j in range(i+1,len(nums)-2):
            # print('node 2')
            k,w = j+1,len(nums)-1
            while k < w:
                sum = nums[i]+nums[j]+nums[k]+nums[w]
                if  sum == target and [nums[i],nums[j],nums[k],nums[w]] not in answer:
                    answer.append([nums[i],nums[j],nums[k],nums[w]])
                if  sum > target:
                    w-=1
                else:
                    k+=1
    return answer    
    

_list, target = random.sample(range(10000), 10000), random.randint(100, 5000)

setup = "from __main__ import myFourSum"
stmt = f"myFourSum({_list}, {target})"
    
print(myFourSum(_list, target))
print(f"Exec. Time: {timeit.timeit(setup = setup, stmt = stmt, number = 10000)}")

print('-' * 50)

setup = "from __main__ import yourFourSum"
stmt = f"yourFourSum({_list}, {target})"
print(yourFourSum(_list, target))
print(f"Exec. Time: {timeit.timeit(setup = setup, stmt = stmt, number = 10000)}")
```

I leave this to you on which one you should choose.

Comment: This rather looks like a bad joke. You fail `nums = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]; target = 0`, returning the same quadruplet four times, not *unique* quadruplets. You fail `nums = [100, 100, 100, 100]; target = 400`, returning *no* quadruplets. And your complexity is O(n^4). And such a tiny case is an irrelevant and terrible benchmark. And better use constants for the test parameters, so that changing them doesn't require changing them twice (cumbersome and errorprone)

Comment: @superb rain yes I agree. I fixed all the errors you mentioned. Regarding the time complexity, maybe we can use divide-and-conquer approach?

Comment: You still fail the target=400 case and you're still benchmarking an irrelevantly tiny case.

Comment: @superbrain Ok man, now it's fixed. I forgot to replace `is` with `==` in a hurry. Anyway I also improved the benchmarking by taking 10000 list items. I hope this helps now.

Comment: Now it gives me `NameError: name '_list' is not defined`.

Comment: That's quite straight forward. It's in line 29 though (if you copy pasted my 2nd snippet).

Comment: I agree it is straight forward to fix. So I suggest you do that :-)

Comment: Works on my end ( ._.')

Comment: I highly doubt that. You probably just didn't wait long enough. You're still stuck waiting for `print(myFourSum(_list, target))`, aren't you? The error occurs after that's finished.

Comment: I guess that works, but creating such a large string is not exactly ideal. Why didn't you just import it? Just like you do with the function?

Comment: Also, what are the result times you got with that benchmark?

Comment: @superbrain I could have just imported it if I was not writing this SO answer. After all, benchmarking my code with author's was absolutely optional. To be honest, I got time limit exceeded with that code, so I didn't get the result. If the author's code is having O(n^6) time complexity, as you said, then having O(n^4) is not that bad if you compare.